# Thread for loading graphics content

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, glx

I'm creating game engine. On windows I had two threads with two contexts that were shared (using wglShareLists). It worked fine. While one thread loaded resources, other was rendering simple loading screen.
On Linux there is no WGL, only glX. I don't know how to correctly use it. Currently my thread code looks like this:

```
LinuxThread::LinuxThread() :
    handle_(0),
    running_(false),
    task_(0),
    useGraphicsContext_(0),
    threadContext_(0),
    threadDrawable_(0),
    dsp_(0)
{
}

LinuxThread::~LinuxThread() {
    finishTask();
    running_ = false;
    glXDestroyContext(dsp_, threadContext_);
}

ULONG LinuxThread::getId() {
    return static_cast<ULONG>(handle_);
}

void LinuxThread::start() {
    running_ = true;
    pthread_create(&handle_, 0, &LinuxThread::staticRun, (void*) this);
}

bool LinuxThread::isRunning() {
    return running_;
}

void LinuxThread::setGraphicsContext(bool state) {
    if (state) {
        Display* dsp = XOpenDisplay(0);
        threadDrawable_ = glXGetCurrentDrawable();
        GLint att[] = { GLX_RGBA, None };
        XVisualInfo* vi = glXChooseVisual(dsp, 0, att);
        GLXContext glc = glXGetCurrentContext();
        bool directlyToScreen = true; // False for x-server display.
        threadContext_ = glXCreateContext(dsp, vi, glc, directlyToScreen);
    }
    useGraphicsContext_ = state;
}

void LinuxThread::setTask(Task* task) {
//  if (useGraphicsContext_) {
//      task->run();
//      delete task;
//      return;
//  }
    finishTask();
    task_ = task;
}

bool LinuxThread::hasTask() {
    return task_ != 0;
}

void LinuxThread::finishTask() {
    while (task_ != 0) {
        usleep(1000);
    }
}

void LinuxThread::stop() {
    running_ = false;
}

void* LinuxThread::staticRun(void* thread) {
    return (void*) ((LinuxThread*) thread)->run();
}

int LinuxThread::run() {
    while (running_) {
        usleep(10000);
        if (task_ != 0) {
            if (useGraphicsContext_) {
                glXMakeCurrent(dsp_, threadDrawable_, threadContext_);
            }
            task_->run();
            if (useGraphicsContext_) {
                glFinish();
                glXMakeCurrent(dsp_, 0, 0);
            }
            delete task_;
            task_ = 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

It crashes with error message like this:

```
nouveau: kernel rejected pushbuf: No such file or directory
nouveau: ch6: krec 0 pushes 1 bufs 14 relocs 0
nouveau: ch6: buf 00000000 00000002 00000006 00000006 00000000
nouveau: ch6: buf 00000001 00000010 00000002 00000002 00000000
nouveau: ch6: buf 00000002 0000000f 00000002 00000002 00000002
nouveau: ch6: buf 00000003 0000000e 00000002 00000000 00000002
nouveau: ch6: buf 00000004 00000007 00000002 00000002 00000002
nouveau: ch6: buf 00000005 0000000a 00000002 00000002 00000000
nouveau: ch6: buf 00000006 0000000b 00000002 00000002 00000000
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: "*On windows I had one thread with OpenGL context. It worked fine. While one thread loaded resources, other was rendering simple loading screen.*" That should not have "worked fine". Not unless you had two contexts with shared resources, or some system that makes sure the same context isn't bound to two different threads at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see a specific problem source, but the threading code complicates things a lot.  In your shoes I would:

1. Try setting `LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=y` before running, to make sure you're not hitting a problem in the nouveau driver. (This will use the internal Mesa Software renderer.)
2. Extract your sharing code into a single thread, make sure it works, then move the known working code back to multiple threads as simply as possible.